# Spring RestTemplate to POST request with Custom Headers and a Request Object

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, resttemplate

In Spring RestTemplate is there a way to send Custom Headers together with a POST Request Object. I have already tried out the `exchange` method which is available. It seems that we can send key value pairs together with a custom headers but not a request object itself attached to the `HttpEntity.` The following code illustrates the attempt and it seems to be `400 BadRequest` for the server.

```
    HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<?> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestDTO, requestHeaders);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity, SomeObject.class);
```

Anyone aware about this situation ? Or is it something which is not possible that Im trying to do ?

Comment: Are you able to post the controller method that the above request is being made to?

Comment: What's the header you are trying to send, "Content-Type"? Are you sure your server supports it?

Comment: @WillKeeling No, I was not able to make a successful request. It seems the request is not being properly created and the server replies 400 Bad Request.

Comment: @RenanIvo yeah. the server supports "Content-Type".

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Yes, It is possible, if use MultiValueMap headers instead of HttpHeaders

Example:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

HttpEntity<ObjectToPass> request = new HttpEntity<ObjectToPass>(objectToPassInstance, headers);

restTemplate.postForObject(urlPost, request, Boolean.class);
```

Boolean.class just because my controller returns boolean at this endpoint (could be anything)

Good luck with coding!

Comment: @Andrey Rudenko how to receive this request and send response in server controller??

Comment: @KJEjava48 1 - It is not about receiving a request, It is about posting data to a server with POST request to this server (for example after clicking "SUBMIT" button.

Comment: @Andrey Rudenko i know that.I just like to know how its server side is working.You are passing an object  like ObjectToPass and a token in header using HttpEntity in your request.So how should you retrieve these token and object in sever?I likes to use this method in my application so that i need to know about its server side also.That's why i am asking you this?

Comment: @KJEjava48 usually I'm getting the Token in a previous GET request (withing some JSON object). And then encode this Token with passw and uname to get "base64Creds"

Comment: @Andrey Rudenko That's ok.But my question is how will you extract this "base64Creds" and "ObjectToPass" in the server when this request reaches your server?

Comment: @KJEjava48 You are not extracting base64Creds you're generating it (using for ex. https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/Base64Utils.html) from username:password:token

Comment: @Andrey Rudenko Then what are you doing in ur server?.I need to pass a token and some data with the rest request.After seeing your answer i am planning to send my token in header and data in body of the restrequest.How will i do this?If its like above how can i retrieve these data in sever??

Comment: >How will i do this? The Code is in the answer > how can i retrieve these data in sever? - I do not know, It depends on a server.

Comment: @Andrey this helped me but why does new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>() work and not HttpEntity<String>?

Comment: I assume ObjectToPass is a custom object.  I have a similar one but it is not  resolving.  This is the reason why I am getting a 400 Bad Request.  My values are present in my custom object but it is not being retrieved in the postForObject method.  Do I need to add some JSON annotations to my custom object?  Thanks.

Comment: @ logixplayer I did some editing in one line HttpEntity<ObjectToPass> request = new HttpEntity<ObjectToPass>(objectToPassInstance, headers); Probably now it is less confusing. Yes - it is custom object (kinda POJO)

Comment: For this to work in recent Spring Security environments you MUSTdisable CSRF-Protection like http.csrf().disable()

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to enable full debug of Spring package. I'm sure you get more
   information about your "400 Bad Request":

   ```xml
   <logger name="org.springframework">
       <level value="DEBUG"/>
   </logger>
   ```
2. Try to send same request with any rest tools (e.g. Rest Console
   Chrome plugin).
3. See what happens on browser debug console ("Network" tab for Chrome, as example).

That steps always help me.

Comment: Only the first answer would apply here. 2 doesn't help because he'd have to recreate the request, which means he might change it, and 3 doesn't help because the client is Java.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. He's not asking how to debug a 400 error. He's asking how to set custom headers in RestTemplate.

Comment: Yes, but firstly you should to know reason of the BAD REQUEST to fix it or do you prefer guess?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using HttpClient 3.x, turn on logging by following [this](https://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/logging.html). If you're using HttpClient 4.x, turn on logging by following [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.3.x/logging.html). That should tell you what's getting sent across the wire, and be a decent starting point for debugging.